# im getting 32767 in my output c++ program

Tags: c++, function, boolean

This code simply takes a number, adds this to another number and then prints the result out. It also says whether the number is high or low. This is all done in a `bool` function:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
bool addition(int num, int num2, int total);

int main()
{
    int num, num2,total;
    cout << "enter a number"<< endl;
    cin >> num;
    cout<< "enter another number" << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    addition(num, num2, total);
    {
        cout <<"the first number is:" <<  num<< " the second number is: "<< num2 <<   endl; 
        cout << "the total is: " << total << endl;
        if (1) {
            cout << "its low" ;
        } else {
            cout << "its high";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}

bool addition (int num, int num2, int total) {
    //total = 0;
    total = num + num2;
    if (total >= 10){
        return 1;
    } else { 
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The problem is this program is ALWAYS saying the number is low and the total is ALWAYS 32767. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing `total` by value, which means `addition()` can't modify `main`'s `total` variable.  Pass by reference instead:

```
bool addition (int num, int num2, int &total)
```

The reason you always get "its low" is because `if (1)` is always true.  Probably you want something like:

```
bool result = addition(num, num2, total);
```

Followed later by:

```
if (result)
```

Comment: Also, he returns -1 instead of 0. IIRC 0 is the only integer that evaluates to false.

Comment: Good catch - didn't notice that one.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `total` by its value. Use pointer or reference instead to modify its value inside the `addition` function.

Besides, returning `1` or `-1` from a function with a boolean return type has same effect, as in C++ any nonzero value evaluates to `true`. Return either `true` or `false` (or either some nonzero value or 0).

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `total` by reference instead of value like this:

```
bool addition (int num, int num2, int &total)
```

instead of

```
bool addition(int num, int num2, int total);
```

Also your condition `if (1)` is always true. So you will always get **low**

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
bool addition (int num, int num2, int &total) {
    total = num + num2;
    return total >= 10;
}

int main()
{
    int num, num2,total;
    cout << "enter a number"<< endl;
    cin >> num;
    cout<< "enter another number" << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    bool additionResult = addition(num, num2, total);
    {
        cout <<"the first number is:" <<  num<< " the second number is: "<< num2 <<   endl; 
        cout << "the total is: " << total << endl;
        if (!additionResult){
            cout << "its low" ;
        }
        else{
            cout << "its high";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```